# Firebase Crashlytics - Use of Advertising ID

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

According to this [page](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/ad-id/), every application submitted to the Play Store must not have the capability to collect both persistent device identifier and Advertising ID. Failure to comply will result in application removal from the Play Store.

Now, I have an application that is collecting persistent device identifier for security purposes, but I still want to use Firebase Crashlytics, as I added the SDK, I noticed that the SDK collects Advertising ID, but I can't find the code that initiate the collection.

So, my question is will the Firebase Crashlytics SDK collect Advertising ID automatically on library inclusion to the app?

If it does, is there any way to disable the collection of Advertising ID?